# Let $X \in [a,b]$ satisfy $\mathbb{E}[\exp(-X)]=1$. Prove $\mathbb{E}[X] \le \frac18(b-a)^2$.

Tags: random-variables, exponential-function, expected-value

I would like to prove the following conjecture.

> **Conjecture.** Let $X$ be a measurable random variable supported on the interval $[a,b]$. If $\mathbb{E}[\exp(-X)]=1$, then $\mathbb{E}[X] \le \frac18 (b-a)^2$.

This is related to [Hoeffding's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma), which shows $\mathbb{E}[\exp(tX)] \le \exp(t\mathbb{E}[X] + \frac18 t^2 (b-a)^2 )$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

If we combine the conjecture with Hoeffding's Lemma, we have $$X \in [a,b] ~~\wedge~~ \mathbb{E}[\exp(-X)]=1 ~~~\implies~~~ \forall t \in \mathbb{R} ~~ \mathbb{E}[\exp(tX)] \le \exp\left(\frac18(b-a)^2 t (t+1)\right). ~~~~~ (*)$$

The hypothesis $\mathbb{E}[\exp(-X)]=1$ is a bit odd. It says that the implication in $(*)$ holds for $t=-1$. (It also holds trivially for $t=0$.) Note that, by Jensen's inequality, $\exp(-\mathbb{E}[X]) \le \mathbb{E}[\exp(-X)] \le 1$, which implies $\mathbb{E}[X] \ge 0$.
Intuitively, $\mathbb{E}[\exp(-X)] \ge 1$ implies that $X$ must have a lot of probability mass near $0$ or below $0$. (Otherwise $X \gg 0$ implies $\exp(-X) \approx 0$.) And this intuition is what the conjecture formalizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly applying the cited lemma, we find that $$\mathbb E(\exp(-X))=1\le\exp\left(-\mathbb E(X)+\frac 1 8 (-1)^2(b-a)^2\right)$$

Take the log of both sides

$$0\le-\mathbb E(X)+\frac 18(b-a)^2$$

Add $\mathbb E(X)$ to both sides.

Where you combined the conjecture with Hoeffding's Lemma, I think you cannot conclude $\exp(t\mathbb E(X))\le\exp\left(t(\frac18 (b-a)^2)\right)$ because $t\in\mathbb R$, so it does not hold if $t<0$.

Comment: Thank you! I suspected Hoeffding's lemma would be the key, but I didn't realize it would be this simple. :-)

Comment: You’re welcome! You did most of the work already by finding the lemma :P